# Use folder instead of drive letter designation in path

Tags: c#, networking, filepath

Is there a way to use mapped network drive folders instead of drives when listing path of file? For example, I have a file with this path location; N:\COMMON\Test.xls and the N: drive is c103d213 on 'c103d213' so the folder is \c103d213\c103d213. I do not want to hard code a drive letter in there because depending on how people setup their drives an N: drive for them could be a completely different than mine.

Comment: How about posting more readible names for server/folders names (`N: drive is c103d213 on 'c103d213' `).

Comment: Just use the UNC name - `@"\\c103d213\c103d213`.

Comment: Look at UNC on Wikipedia.

Comment: @Tim What do you mean?

Comment: @I4V - There was no point (that I could see, at least) to your comment.  It struck me as rather flippant and non-useful, at least with no further context.

Comment: @Tim, you are the man! I was having a hard time searching how to solve this problem because I had never heard of UNC before.

Comment: @Tim And you decided to be rude instead of saying your last comment?

Comment: @I4V - Rude?  You can take it that way if you want, though it wasn't meant to be rude.  To be honest, I thought your initial comment was rude and I posted my first reaction.  In any case, you can elaborate on your comment if you want or not - OP got the answer to his question, and at the end of the day that's what we're all here for.

Comment: @Tim when using  names like `c103d213` for servers and folders(which are the same for this question) it is hard to follow. I don't know how you found it *rude*, but anyway, as you said, OP got his answer and I found another personality that doesn't try to understand the comment before replying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WMI to get the mapping. I've used this in a project before:

```
string mapping = null;

var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\cimv2", "select Caption,ProviderName from Win32_MappedLogicalDisk");
foreach (ManagementObject drive in searcher.Get())
{
    if (drive["Caption"].ToString() == driveLetter)
    {
        mapping = drive["ProviderName"].ToString();
        break;
    }
}
```